# How do i fix this missing dll error in sublime text

Tags: c++, c, windows, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I tried up setting up sublime text for C and CPP. As a trial, I wrote a basic output program to test it out. But during compilation I got this error, "The code execution cannot proceed because libmpfr-6.dll was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix this problem."

Comment: The easiest would be copying the missing dll into the same directory where the executable lives.

Comment: i dont know which directory that would be

Comment: How so? Don't you know where is your program?

Comment: oh you mean location of sublime?

Comment: @vahancho i tried pasting the dll, but it didnt work

Comment: Sublime doesn't compile your code, it uses some external program that you tell it to for that. As such, if you see an error during compilation, it's that tool that's giving you the error, not Sublime. If you get the error during compilation, the DLL is missing from whatever tool you're using to compile, not Sublime or the folder where your program lives.

Comment: Im using mingw so I've to paste that dll in that directory or what?